# How to convert font to image(PNG) in DirectWrite format using Php?

Tags: php, html, json

I need to develop a PHP code through which a user is able convert Fonts(Text) into Images(PNG), in the same time the user will have the option to change the images into Grayscale, GDI and DirectWrite,during submitting the form. So the first two i.e. Grayscale, GDI are working well but I cnt develop the DirectWrite. Any help?

Comment: repost of [How to convert font to image(PNG) in DirectWrite format using Php???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678204/how-to-convert-font-to-imagepng-in-directwrite-format-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

[DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368038.aspx) seems to be a Windows API designed for direct rendering of text.

PHP has [spotty support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.windows.php) for calling Win32 API functions.  Your best bet may be writing a program in a Windows-native language (like C# or VB.net) that creates the image using the proper API calls, and then simply calling that program from your PHP script.